# USB-C Docking station creates static noise whenever I move my mouse (which isn't connected to it)

Tags: laptop, mouse, usb-c, docking-station

I recently purchased a TARGUS USB-C Docking station with PD passthrough.

I have connected a VGA monitor to it, as well as using it for passthrough power to the laptop.

My mouse is connected to a USB port on the laptop (Latitude 5510).

Whenever I move my mouse, either using the attached USB mouse or the trackpad, the docking station makes a static noise, a bit like a modem.

If I remove the passthrough power, the noise stops - but I don't see the connection between moving the mouse and the PD passthrough. I presume there's some kind of hardware fault / feedback loop going on?

I've tried plugging the dock into a different wall socket to the laptop, but that doesn't help.

Can anyone suggest anything to explain this, and a way to stop it happening?

Comment: Did you try another mouse?

Comment: Yes, even with the external mouse unplugged it still happens when I move the trackpad that's built in to the laptop

Comment: Perhaps the PSU of the computer is not enough for the dock?

Comment: The dock works - I can have multiple USB devices and a monitor attached - it just makes that noise. The dock is connected to the mains as it's passing the power through to the PC through USB C, so the PSU of the laptop shouldn't matter? The noise only comes when the dock is connected to the mains

Comment: If the dock and the mouse are power-connected everything is possible, but I'm puzzled by the noise happening with the mouse disconnected. Try it when booting in Safe mode.

Comment: Safe mode doesn't make a difference

Comment: Something is leaking RF. Something else is picking it up. Isolating which is which & then adequately shielding it is frankly a nightmare. The usual 'fix' is to use better-isolated components.